# Does Firestore index field order matter?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

For one of my collections I created the following index:

- `createdOn`: timestamp (Ascending)
- `ordinal`: number (Ascending)
- `parent`: reference (Ascending)

However, when I run a query that uses all three fields, firestore won't fetch anything and is suggesting this index instead (**the last two fields are swapped**):

- `createdOn`: timestamp (Ascending)
- `parent`: reference (Ascending)
- `ordinal`: number (Ascending)

I also tried to change the order of `where*` and `orderBy` in the query but it didn't have any effect. So, now I have two indexes and don't understand why one of them isn't working and the other one is fine.

Why do I need a different index? The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) don't mention it (at least here).

---

The query I'm using is this one:

```
    private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun texts(languageId: String, storyId: String): Task<QuerySnapshot> {
        return firestore
            .collection("/languages/$languageId/texts")
            .whereIn("createdOn", dates) // <-- List<Timestamp>
            .whereEqualTo("parent", firestore.document("/languages/$languageId/stories/$storyId"))
            .orderBy("ordinal", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .get()
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the exact query (or queries) that doesn't work the way you expect.  Is there a query where your index *does* work?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added the query code. It works with the second index but not with the first one.

Comment: Consider posting your question to the official Firestore discussion group.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: im having a similar experience, it seems that the order of the fields does matter and the index always wants the `orderBy` field(s) last

Comment: @MikeG awsome! I've just realized that indeed, it's `ordinal` that I use for sorting and the second index has this field as the last one. Good catch! Firestore is great but there are way too many _hidden_ surprises all over the place that you usually discover when something doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @MikeG in the comment, I can confirm that, the sequence for the `where` field is not important, but `orderBy` field must always be last. It is good practice to break down the index into 2 indices:

- createdOn (Ascending), ordinal (Ascending)
- parent (Ascending), ordinal (Ascending)

Firestore will merge them together while query, and it can save some cost and also reuse the index at different scenario.